# Chef LWRPs - how to use

Tags: chef-infra

I've tried to use chef to make development environment with Vagrant. **I'm stuck with the part of installing rubies versions within rbenv when I run `vagrant provision`**. I use `gem librarian` to download cookbooks and this is my current Vagrantfile : 
https://github.com/rhacker/vagrant-rails/blob/master/Vagrantfile

This is my repo which stores Cheffile and Vagrantfile : https://github.com/rhacker/vagrant-rails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `site-cookbooks/rbenv/recipes/install.rb` with

```
include_recipe "rbenv::default"
include_recipe "rbenv::ruby_build"

rbenv_ruby "1.9.3-p194"
```

Now in your `Vagrantfile`, change to

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "lucid32"
  config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.33"
  config.vm.customize do |vm|
    vm.memory_size = 386
  end
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
    chef.add_recipe "git"
    chef.add_recipe "openssl"
    chef.add_recipe "postgresql"
    chef.add_recipe "rbenv::install"
    chef.add_recipe "unicorn"
  end
end
```