# Vagrant with librarian-chef installing ruby via ruby_build & rbenv

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, rbenv

over the last few weeks i have had to reinstall my whole working environment a few times and it can take a while so now i have an ambitious idea to use vagrant and librarian-chef to create my working environment so that all i have to do is run a bash script and viola i am in.

so the first time i did this was solo vagrant i went in and did everything and packaged it and it was great for only a while.. the package was 600mb so next idea was to have chef do it all.  but i have never worked with chef before so i found [librarian-chef](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian) basically i `librarian-chef init` and it makes a cheffile that you can specify cookbooks mine looks like this

```
site 'http://community.opscode.com/api/v1'

cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'git'
cookbook 'build-essential'
cookbook 'ruby_build',
  git: 'git://github.com/fnichol/chef-ruby_build'
cookbook 'rbenv',
  git: 'git://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv'
cookbook 'sqlite',
  git: 'git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/sqlite.git'
cookbook 'nodejs',
  git: 'http://github.com/mdxp/nodejs-cookbook'
cookbook 'mysql',
  git: 'git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql.git'
cookbook 'redis',
  git: 'git://github.com/brianbianco/redisio.git'
cookbook 'zlib',
  git: 'git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/zlib'
cookbook 'wkhtmltopdf',
  git: 'git://github.com/firstbanco/chef-wkhtmltopdf.git'
```

and you tell vagrant and chef to build these when you call `vagrent up`

in the vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks","site-cookbooks"]
  chef.add_recipe "apt"
  chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
  chef.add_recipe "git"
  chef.add_recipe "ruby_build"
  chef.add_recipe "rbenv::install"
  chef.add_recipe "sqlite"
  chef.add_recipe "nodejs"
  chef.add_recipe "mysql"
  chef.add_recipe "redis"
  chef.add_recipe "zlib"
  chef.add_recipe "wkhtmltopdf"
end
```

now i was wondering if i could get `ruby_build` to install 1.9.3-p290 i found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826311/chef-lwrps-how-to-use) which seemed to have the answer but i am getting the following

```
Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[2013-05-23T14:31:18+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.14.2 ***
[2013-05-23T14:31:18+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[apt]", "recipe[build-essential]", "recipe[git]", "recipe[ruby_build]", "recipe[rbenv::install]", "recipe[sqlite]", "recipe[nodejs]", "recipe[mysql]", "recipe[redis]", "recipe[zlib]", "recipe[wkhtmltopdf]"] from JSON
[2013-05-23T14:31:18+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[apt], recipe[build-essential], recipe[git], recipe[ruby_build], recipe[rbenv::install], recipe[sqlite], recipe[nodejs], recipe[mysql], recipe[redis], recipe[zlib], recipe[wkhtmltopdf]]
[2013-05-23T14:31:18+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [apt, build-essential, git, ruby_build, rbenv::install, sqlite, nodejs, mysql, redis, zlib, wkhtmltopdf]
[2013-05-23T14:31:18+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for precise64
[2013-05-23T14:31:18+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2013-05-23T14:31:18+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
--------------------------------
could not find recipe ruby_build for cookbook rbenv

[2013-05-23T14:31:19+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-05-23T14:31:19+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-05-23T14:31:19+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-05-23T14:31:19+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound: could not find recipe ruby_build for cookbook rbenv
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

how can i get ruby installed as well through ruby build is it possible or is this not possible

Answer (score 0):

Librarian will install your cookbooks locally, but they aren't transferred to the remote vagrant box. You'll need to use the [Vagrant Librarian Chef plugin](https://github.com/jimmycuadra/vagrant-librarian-chef).

See also:

- [Berkshelf](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf)
- [Vagrant Berkshelf](https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf)

Answer (score 0):

try adding ruby_build to the run list:

`"run_list": [ "ruby_build", "recipe[main]" ]`